# Twilio - is there a place to find out formatting requirements?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have been all through the Twilio API docs, and I can't seem to find what requirements they have for certain inputs.  For instance, I found that if I am searching for a number in a city, the city can't have any punctuation in it, but sometimes the abbreviated name is required.  For instance, searching for `in_locality="Ft. Worth"` and `in_locality="Ft Worth"` won't work, but `in_locality="Fort Worth"` does.  Oddly though, other abbreviations are somewhat required, like `in_locality="St George"` works, but `in_locality="Saint George"` does not, nor does `in_locality="St. George"`

Are there any rules for this written down anywhere, or do I just have to figure out every permutation of an abbreviated city name by magic, and try them all?

Comment: Twilio has a lot of APIs, which one are you referring to specifically? Maybe you could get a phone number from the city and then use its locality to search for others in the same area.

Comment: I'm using the Twilio Rest API using the python SDK.  An example call would be:  `numbers = client.available_phone_numbers("US").local.list(in_region="TX", in_locality="Fort Worth")`

Comment: I'm not seeing any useful list of cities provided by Twilio. Could you use something like finding numbers within a distance of major cities and then parse their localities to compile your own list?

Comment: That seems like an extreme option, but I'm trying to stupid proof it for customers.  It would be nice if Twilio were able to accept the data like they do with their own website.  I can put all of those in the search on their site, and it will come up with numbers just fine.

What I'm considering is using Google's geolocation API to get coordinates of a city, which is very forgiving about names, then doing the search within a radius of those coordinates.  I was hoping for a one step solution though.

Comment: Maybe you can get some support from them. They answer questions on here sometimes.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm investigating this internally and will get back to you when I know a bit more.

Comment: Thank you Philnash.  To explain why I need this, I am programming for a platform where the customer should be able to enter their chosen city and a list of numbers be produced.  Since humans are notoriously bad at being consistent, it would be nice to be able to at least know if there are rules for formatting.  I understand that only letters are valid, which is an easy work around.  It is the inconsistent way that abbreviation is handled that is going to be a problem.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no API to get the list of localities and the correct format. There's a chance that this sort of thing will come in the future and I will follow up on that internally, but I'm afraid your best bet right now is probably to use the geolocation plan that you mentioned earlier for now.